# Text keeps going outside div when appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to append text into a div but it keeps going outside the div box like this https://gyazo.com/a3b7bbd13c2934e653c7b5d9166d1ba4 . I want it to continue down just like any other document. I have tried overflow and whitespace but nothing seems to work, I need some suggestions. Thanks for your time!

This is the code associeted with getting and posting the text. Text is taken from

```
if(newclassexpected === true){$(".siteview").append("<div class=\"" + definedclass + "\"><\/div>");
                             newclassexpected = false;}


fonthandler();
      $(definedclass2).css("display", "none");
    $(definedclass2).css({
      "width": width,
      "height": height,
      "float": "left",
      "border": "solid 2px black",
      "background": bgcolor,
      "font": fontcomponent,
      "color": txcolor,


});
  var test1 = $("#textbox").val();
$(definedclass2).fadeIn(100);
$(definedclass2).empty();  
$(definedclass2).prepend("<p>" + test1+ "</p>");
```

Comment: It clipped the last line, "Text is taken from <textfield> in html"

Comment: Edit your post rather than comment on it and make a fiddle rather than link to your site. :)

Comment: @jmargolisvt Ye,sorry I should have done that, and it is currently only on my computer not uploaded anywhere. But Michael solved it for me, but thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `word-break: break-all;` to break anywhere in a word like that.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much, as soon as it lets me I will mark it as answered!

Answer (score 0):

Since the text that is shown in image have no space you need to explicitly split the word which can be done by `word-wrap:break-word;` in your CSS.

Comment: Perfect, this works even better that Michaels but with the same technique! Thanks to you both!

Comment: @noxcore You're welcome! and accept the answer so the question could be closed :)